# Category with morphisms from $n\to m$ integers as $m \times n$ matrices?

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, category-theory

I'm just getting started with Category Theory and am reading "Category Theory in Context" by Emily Riehl. In Chapter 1, page 4, she describes in example 1.1.4. (i) the Category $\text{Mat}_R$, which is the category of positive integers $m, n$ as objects, and the set of morphisms is defined as $f: m \rightarrow n$, which are $m \times n$ matrices with values in $R$, if $R$ is a ring.

I don't really understand this definition. Does it mean that these are simply vectors being mapped to other vectors? And the map represents the matrix itself?

The definition of composition via matrix multiplication seems to shed more lights onto this. I would assume that my assumption above is correct?

If not, can someone explain to me what exactly this category is or means?

Comment: The point is that the definition of "category" is that it's very general. It just says "there are some things called objects and some things called morphisms and an operation called composition and they have some properties". It never says the morphisms must be actual functions. Here a category is being defined whose objects are natural numbers, whose morphisms are certain matrices and whose composition operation is given by matrix multiplication. It is supposed to be an example of an *abstract* category. (as it happens you can interpret it concretely but that's not the point).

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen This is an answer - not a comment. Please post answers as answers so that they can be accepted as such and are more visible.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg, apologies for my misuse of the comments. I was concerned that this fairly basic/common question would count as a duplicate of something, and I understand that answering dupes is frowned upon. So I left a comment hoping it would be helpful to OP. EG I'm not sure I'd have much more to say in an answer than the sum of the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2317909 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/309653 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1594658 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3996882 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2000595 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4259184 ...

Comment: ... https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1905931 https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1947261 The Q is also not very clear, and I was hoping OP might clarify that indeed that answers the Q, or provide more more detail so it's clearer exactly what an answer needs to address. Also I personally prefer to write answers which go into more detail than my comment above, but I don't always have time to do that. Of course I never mind if someone else uses part/all of my comment as part/all of their answer! Is all of that unfounded? If so I'll try to answer instead of comment in situations like this in future.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it mean that these are simply vectors being mapped to other vectors? And the map represents the matrix itself?

Consider the vector space $\mathbb R^n$. Now, are there any other $n$-dimensional real vector spaces? No, not really.  $\mathbb R^n$ is a good representative for all of them. That means we can discuss all finite dimensional real vector spaces as $\mathbb R^n$ for nonnegative integers $n$.

But does the $\mathbb R$ contribute anything vital?  No, not as long as we remember it's in the context.  Let's just drop it and write $n$ instead of $\mathbb R^n$.  **Let's assume we always use the standard bases for $\mathbb R^n$.**  Then we know the linear maps from $\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m$ in 1-1 correspondence with $m\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb R$.

By just talking about $n$ as if it were $\mathbb R^n$, and maps between vector spaces as if they were just matrices, we can still do all of linear algebra.  Notice here in defining morphisms you have not even mentioned what linearity is yet.  It's a property they have, yes, but you can get this far without mentioning it.  You don't even have to talk about elements of the vector space to discuss their maps and how they compose, it's just given as matrix multiplication.

This is to be contrasted with defining the category by saying the objects to be "all finite dimensional $\mathbb R$-vector spaces," and morphisms are "the linear transformations between them."  This description does not rely on bases or coordinates *at all*.  One could say it has a lot more objects than the other category though.

Nevertheless, the two are equivalent.  The first one is what you'd call a [skeleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(category_theory)) of the second.

Comment: And if $R$ is a ring, we talk about $R$-modules equipped with a finite basis. (I prefer not to say free $R$-modules here, since it is well-known that $R^n \cong R^m$ can happen for $n \neq m$.)